# Help proving a set is not compact (without Heine-Borel Theorem).

Tags: general-topology

Show directly from the definition (that is without using the Heine-Borel theorem that the set $\{(x,y) \in R^2:x^2+y^2 \ge \}$ is not a compact subset of $R^2$.

I'm not sure where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just cover your set by a union of concentric open balls with increasing radii. This will be an open cover that has no finite subcover.